# How should I handle validation error using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a form in html, I'll do the validation on the server side. If the validation fails, the `errorDiv` will be updated, otherwise the `resultDiv` will be updated.

I have two options to handle this. My friend said the validation failure should handle in the on success part of ajax call. While I think put the logic in the error part might be better.

Some of his concerns might be:

- The validation error is not some error like network connection
  failure which should use some status code like 400; or any server
  side error, which using the status code 500.

My concern is:

- If we put the logic in the error part, the logic seems more clear;
- we can use some other status code (although I don't know right now)
  rather than 400, 500 to indicate the validation error.

My friend's Option 1:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:someFormData,     
    url:'/submitToServer',
    success:function(data,textStatus) {
        if(data.hasValidationError){
            $('#errorDiv').html(data);
        }else{
            $('#resultDiv').html(data);
        }
    }
});
```

My Option 2:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:someFormData,     
    url:'/submitToServer',
    success:function(data,textStatus) {
        $('#resultDiv').html(data);
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){
        if(textStatus==500)
             $('#errorDiv').html(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I do know both ways can handle the validation errors, but which way is better? Which way are you using? Please give me some pros and cons...

Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Hmm this question is not really on topic here, its a person opinion thing, personally I would through an error from the server side. That way if you ever reuse the code its clear there is an error.

Answer (score 1):

i have to agree with your friend. the error part is not designed for that use. the official document it clearly say:

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives
>   three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a
>   string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and
>   "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the
>   textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal
>   Server Error."

so the error callback must only be used to treat error that belong to the HTTP status not your own validation rules.